# Переписать с php на javascript

Tags: php, javascript

Помогите переписать с php на js

```
function time_m($res){
    //$month = floor( $res / 2592000 );
    $day = floor( $res / 86400 );
    $hour = ( $res / 3600 ) % 24;
    $min = ( $res / 60 ) % 60;
    $sec = $res % 60;

    if ($day>0) {
    echo $day.'д '.$hour.'ч '.$min.'мин';
    }elseif($hour>0){
    echo $hour.'ч '.$min.'мин';
    }elseif ($min>0) {
    echo $min.'мин';
    }else{echo 'пусто';}
    }
```

Comment: Прочитайте пожалкйста правила форума. Тут никто не делает за вас работу. А только помогают в решении проблем с которыми вы сами не справитесь. Разобратсья с синтаксисом javascript вы сможете вполне, если владете php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function time_m($res) {
    // const $month = Math.floor( $res / 2592000 );
    const $day = Math.floor( $res / 86400 );
    const $hour = ( $res / 3600 ) % 24;
    const $min = ( $res / 60 ) % 60;
    const $sec = $res % 60;
    if ($day>0) {
        console.log(`${$day}д ${$hour}ч ${$min}мин`);
    }else if($hour>0){
        console.log(`${$hour}ч ${$min}мин`);
    }else if ($min>0) {
        console.log(`${$min}мин`);
    }else{
        console.log('пусто');
    }
}


time_m(3600)
```